# React-select async options not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I would like to display the search results in my `react-select` list, when a user clicks the option, it loads the data in full in a table below.

Here is my `loadIptions`

```
getMovies(e){ 
axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${e}`)
   .then((response) => {
    return {options: response.data.Title}
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

I'm sending the function to my search:

```
    render() {
      return (
         <div className="container">
           <SearchForm onkeydown={this.getMovies}  />
           <MovieList movie={this.state.movie}/>
       </div>
 );
}
```

However I cannot this to display in the input, it stays on loading state:

```
<Select.Async
 name="form-field-name"
 value=""
 loadOptions={this.props.onkeydown}
/>
```

Any ideas how I get it to show the title?

Comment: You sure response.data.Title is an actual array of values? You've also check your promise is getting returned

Comment: I've tried returning this:

`return [{ value: response.data.imdbID, label: response.data.Title }];`

Comment: Please check below. Your function isnt actually returning anything, just making the api call. Also make sure that response.data.Title is an actual array of values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function isnt actually returning anything

Change this:

```
getMovies(e){ 
axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${e}`)
   .then((response) => {
    return {options: response.data.Title}
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

To:

```
getMovies(e){ 
return axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${e}`)
   .then((response) => {
    return {options: response.data.Title}
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```